# Join tables by child table id without inner select

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have two tables (owner and employee) and a mapping table (owner_employee)

I need a select statement which gets all owner employees by **employee_id** without using inner selects

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
[...Joins here...]
WHERE e.id = 1
```

should return

```
owner | employee
1     |   1
1     |   2
```

**Owner table**

```
id | title
----------
1  |  a
2  |  b
3  |  c
```

**Employee table**

```
id | title
----------
1  |  a
2  |  a
3  |  b
4  |  c
```

**Owner_Employee**

```
id_owner | id_employee
----------------------
1        |    1
1        |    2
2        |    3
3        |    4
```

Working implementation of inner select here (probably working, because I rewrote it from original example)

```
SELECT *
 FROM owner_employee oe
 JOIN owner o  ON o.id = oe.id_owner                                                 
 JOIN employee e ON e.id = oe.id_employee
 WHERE o.id in 
 (SELECT id_owner 
  FROM owner_employee oe
  WHERE oe.id_employee in (1))
```

Comment: Your expected result conflicts with the condition `WHERE e.id = 1`. It's not possible, unless you've misstated one or the other.

Comment: please check the querty `(SELECT id` looks wrong, and should give a error message. as there are two tables with `id` columns but neither is `owner_employee`

Comment: `without using inner selects` You just lost me.

Comment: suspect he means subselects

Comment: What do the rows in the tables mean, and what is an "owner employee"? Somehow owner 1 is employee 1 and is also employee 2?? How is "all owner employees by employee_id" different than SELECT id_employee FROM owner_employee? Your own query doesn't return that.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT oe.*,o.*,e.*
 FROM owner_employee AS z 
 JOIN owner_employee oe on oe.id_owner = z.id_owner
 JOIN owner o  ON o.id = oe.id_owner
 JOIN employee e ON e.id = oe.id_employee
 WHERE z.id_employee in (1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query code you give (which does not return what your text asks for) is the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM owner_employee oe
JOIN owner o  ON o.id = oe.id_owner                                                 
JOIN employee e ON e.id = oe.id_employee
WHERE oe.id_employee = 1
```

But what your text asks for, "all owner employees by employee_id" apparently doesn't make sense. Becuase from your data one owner can have more than one id_employee.

If you want "all id_owners and their id_employees":

```
SELECT * FROM owner_employee
```

IF you want "id_employees of all owners":

```
SELECT id_employee FROM owner_employee
```

Or maybe you want "all owners, each by one of their employee ids"?